# this and super keywords in Java constructors

Tags: java, multithreading, sockets, connection

I'm new to threads and am struggling to understand how to implement them. I have a basic understanding of what they are and how they work.

Right now I have two files and they are connected by a socket and I can writebytes back and forth. The purpose of this assignment is to enable multi-usability. By that I mean I want to be able to type a message and be able to receive one simultaneously. This is where threading comes in.

I've read articles on the oracle pages and many other sites that have tutorials for threading and I'm still lost on how to implement threads. What I know so far is:

1. You can either extend or implement the Thread Class. I'm currently extending the Thread Class.
2. I also know that by creating a constructor you can call that constructor as a Thread.

What I'm confused about:

1. A lot of tutorials use the "this" keyword in reference and I'm confused about what it is and why you would use it.
2. A lot of tutorials also use the "super" keyword. I'm always confused as to what it is and why you would use it.

I can provide further information and my current code for connecting these two classes if you think it will help. Any feedback relevant to this topic is very much appreciated.

Comment: Read Java Concurrency in Practice - it is the best book on applied concurrency I've read for any language.

Comment: Have you read the Java Tutorial on [Using the this Keyword](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/thiskey.html) and [Using the Keyword super](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/super.html)?

Comment: I don't want to be rude, but threads are very complex beasts to program correctly. And if you haven't understood what `this` and `super` are, it's much too soon for you to mess with threads. Start with the basics, and learn what objects and inheritance are.

Comment: If you're having trouble with `this` and `super` your problems are more basic than threading.  You need to go through a basic Java tutorial (try the one on Oracle's site) to understand what it means to extend a class vs implementing an interface.

Comment: It seems you are a new Java developer (because you don't know what are `this` and `super` keywords). I don't think you can go right to concurrent and multi thread programming just now. You must know Java well, you must know the features the core language provides for concurrency and then start programming threads.

Comment: @Amir pashazadeh Tell that to my professor who has this assignment due on friday. :P

Answer (score 2):

You may want to look at Java's documentation for [this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/thiskey.html) and [super](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/super.html) first.

Update:
Based on your comments, it looks like it is calling the constructor.

```
this(/*args*/)
```

can often be used to call an alternate constructor of the object.  Same with

```
super(/*args*/)
```

Comment: This is not an answer; it should be a comment.

Comment: I understand this when it is in reference to a variable. You reference the object, not the value of the object, and then you can use that however you please, but I don't understand what they're doing when they use it in regards to that method.

The line this(0, 0, width, height);

Comment: This is from the link you provided on the java tutorial of this.

public class Rectangle {
    private int x, y;
    private int width, height;
        
    public Rectangle() {
        this(0, 0, 0, 0);
    }
    public Rectangle(int width, int height) {
        this(0, 0, width, height);
    }
    public Rectangle(int x, int y, int width, int height) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
        this.width = width;
        this.height = height;
    }
    ...
}

Comment: @Aaron where is that code located?  Could you update your answer with the context?

Comment: @AaronDavis, so in fact your question seems to have nothing to do with threads, but about using `this` and `super` in constructors. Please reword your post and add a proper title. It doesn't help if you post unclearly worded questions with a misleading title.

Comment: @GrailsGuy, it's in the `this` Tutorial you (and I :-) referenced.

Comment: It is about threads, because that's what I have to use for this assignment, however it seems my knowledge of super and this needs to come first.

Comment: @Aaron, yeah you should probably look into those first.  And for reference, it might help to update your question with code when you ask the question, I didn't know you had seen the tutorials and were referencing that code.  Please update your question and we will respond best we can.

Comment: @AaronDavis, the line `this(0, 0, width, height)` calls another constructor of the same class, the one having 4 parameters (the last one in the code sample).

Comment: In regards to the this keyword, is it correct to say that you can use this to reference an object, method, or constructor of the class that you're currently in?

Comment: @Aaron Just the Object, in most cases.  In other programming languages, that may not always be the case (see Javascript), but in Java I believe this always refers to the Object you are in.

Comment: @AaronDavis, no. `this` refers either to the enclosing object (in general) or to one of its constructors (only within a constructor, when used with braces after, as in a method call). `this.x = x` is an example to the former, `this(0, 0, width, height)` to the latter.

Comment: Why would you want to use this? could you not simply reference your variable or constructor by its name?

Comment: @Aaron I imagine clarity of understanding would be one reason.  If you're ever writing any kind of code using Reflection or in languages that allow dynamic methods, 'this' would make it easier, as well.

Comment: @GrailsGuy What do you mean by "clarity of understanding"? As in the example above if you reference x, are you not referencing x? Why must it be this.x?

Comment: @Aaron it seems you have a lot of questions on the topic, and it may be helpful to find a resource that may be better to help you understand than SO.  However, to answer your last question, if I have both a property and a local variable called x, this.x will refer to the property, while just x will refer to the local variable.  Using this notation right away may help prevent this conflict.